# Hindi & some english characters not displaying properly

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have 2 copies of the same project sharing Common Database in MySql.The 1st one is in simple PHP, while the 2nd one is the CodeIgniter v3.1.3 of the 1st one.When i run both the projects on localhost, i observe that the project made with simple PHP displays the Hindi and some english characters with apostrophe correctly.On the other hand, the CI project does not render the said characters properly(i.e some weird characters like ?*` etc).

On every page i have:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
```

in config.php:

```
$config['charset'] = 'UTF-8';
```

in database.php:

```
'char_set' => 'utf8',
'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
```

I searched the net for possible solutions, but none seems to work for me.Please advice what else should i try.Thanks

Comment: try `utf8_unicode_ci` I am not sure.

Comment: Is that `<meta>` tag appearing in the `<head>` of each page, preferably right at the top?

Comment: Yes, just right after the <head> tag

Comment: Are both apps accessing the same data (ie, same DB, same tables, same columns, etc)?

Comment: Try switching the meta tag for the HTML5 version ~ `<meta charset="utf-8">`

Comment: @Phil, both the apps use the same DB, same table and same everything.I used the HTML5 version of meta tag, still the problem persists :(

Comment: is it related to foreign_chars.php in codeigniter?